# Problemas de configuração do Apache

Tags: apache, servidor, zend

Eu estou tentando fazer o deploy de um projeto que está usando o Zend. Esse projeto está em uma sub-pasta do site( site.com/projetos/nome-projeto ). O site está em um VPS, ao qual eu tenho acesso root. O servidor é o Apache 2.4.7. Configurei um VirtualHost para o projeto, para que ele tivesse uma raiz própria e não a raiz do site. A raiz do projeto ficou então na pasta public dele, como o manual do Zend pede. Fiz isso no arquivo /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf. Abaixo, o conteúdo do arquivo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com.br
    ServerAlias www.site.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site/
    Alias /projetos/nome-projeto/ /var/www/html/site/projetos/nome-projeto/public$

    <Directory /var/www/html/site/projetos/nome-projeto/public>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com.br
    ServerAlias www.site.com.br

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

O primeiro VirtualHost é o VirtualHost do projeto. O segundo é o VirtualHost do site. Quando eu acesso site.com/projetos/nome-projeto ele lista os arquivos da pasta public do projeto, mesmo tendo um index.php nele. E se eu tento entrar no index.php "manualmente" ou entrar em alguma rota que eu defini no Zend, como site.com/projetos/nome-projeto/rota, ele me dá o erro 404.

Em /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, tenho algumas configurações que podem ser relevantes para a questão:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/site/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/site/projetos/nome-projeto/public/>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Antecipadamente agradeço.

Atualização:

Vocês podem ver o php.ini aqui: http://www.writeurl.com/text/huteb5d0earyzcs071r8/02ig7jc8q4y3rps8k3i3/0m33188y9nd42vot2zpg

Atualização 2:

Abaixo, o apache2.conf:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/site/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>



<Directory /var/www/html/site/projetos/nome-projeto/public/>
    RewriteEngine On
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>



#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Não vejo as configurações no PHP, você está usando apache2handler ou FastCGI?

Comment: apache2handler. Não conheço muito de servidores. Dei uma pesquisada e criei um script simples com apenas um phpinfo() e vi que a Server API é Apache 2.0 Handler.

Comment: Coloquei o apache2.conf. Não tenho o httpd.conf. Desculpe pelo link externo.

Comment: Não...eu tenho acesso total ao VPS. É que eu não encontrei esse arquivo. Procurando na net parece que em versões mais recentes do Ubuntu( eu estou usando a 12 ), ele foi substituído pelo apache2.conf. Veja: http://ubuntugods.com/httpd-conf-location-ubuntu. Parece que é algo mais do Ubuntu, que decidiu usar o apache2.conf.

Comment: Sim, tenho muitos arquivos nessa pasta.

Comment: Eu não encontrei essas linhas, mas eu usei o comando "a2enmod rewrite" e recebi uma resposta informando que o módulo já estava habilitado. E no mods_enabled tem um "rewrite.load". O problema não está só com as rotas. Nem o index.php ele parece não estar executando automaticamente, quando nenhum arquivo é executado, pois quando a URL é site.com/projetos/nome-projeto/, ele deveria executar o index.php, mas ele só lista os arquivos da pasta. E isso só acontece nesse VirtualHost. Fora dele, em qualquer outra pasta do site, funciona tudo, inclusive URL's amigáveis. Vlw pela ajuda, Guilherme.

Comment: Sim...ao executar "a2enmod dir" também aparece a mensagem que o módulo já está habilitado.

Comment: Cara minha ultima alternativa rs, como não parece um problema com o `DirectoryIndex index.php`, então pode ser como o "index.php", você poderia renomear o index.php para orig_index.php e adicionar um index.php na pasta com o conteudo `<?php echo 'oi'; ?>` e tentar abrir a URL manualmente?

Comment: Acho que você sofrendo com um erro de conceito aqui. Não sei como está seu projeto, mas vou tentar lhe fornecer uma visão geral de como funciona os VirtualHosts do Apache, talvez consiga encaixar o seu projeto aí. Primeiro, os VirtualHosts servem para você hospedar diversos hosts em uma mesmo servidors. Por exemplo, vários domínios e subdomínios sendo servidos pelo mesmo apache. Mas isso NÃO SE APLICA para subpastas como por exemplo www.example.com/meuprojeto. Segundo, não se deve alterar o arquivo 000-default.conf a menos que seja realmente necessário.

Comment: Você deve criar um novo arquivo na pasta `sites-available` como por exemplo: `meuprojeto.conf` e colocar nesse arquivo seu VirtualHost configurado. Depois você ativa usando o comando `sudo a2ensite meuprojeto` para o Apache disponibilizar seu novo VirtualHost. Não sei como funciona o Zend, mas geralmente os frameworks possuem uma pasta pública onde você deve apontar o DocumentRoot do VirtualHost para ela, para que os arquivos do framework fiquem protegidos.

Comment: Opa...acabei delegando essa tarefa para outra pessoa, que conhece mais sobre servidores...eu sei muito pouco. @RicardoGiaviti, mas como eu faria se eu quisesse ter uma pasta raiz para site.com/ e outra para site.com/diretorio? Porque se site.com/ não usa Zend, ele tem a raiz dele. E site.com/diretorio tendo o Zend nele, não precisa ter a sua própria pasta raiz? E o Zend funciona exatamente da forma que você falou. Vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Aí você tem duas opções. Uma é usando o .htaccess e fazendo rewrite e outra é configurando um Alias no VirtualHost do site.com. Mas não há como configurar dois DocumentRoot em um mesmo VirtualHost.

Comment: No caso, a solução que o cara que fez esse job pra mim encontrou foi definir uma variável CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT com a raiz do projeto. A DOCUMENT_ROOT é como vc falou, não dá pra definir uma específica para o projeto.

Comment: > Depois posso criar um ambiente em casa, usando o [ISPConfig3](https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/4b50de4a24a162add15f)
para ver como ele vai fazer o conf, ai o eu post aqui, mas você mesmo pode instalar uma VM com ISPConfig3, no meu [Blog](http://www.linuxpro.com.br) e canal do Youtube tem vários howtos de instalação do ISPConfig3, vai lhe ajudar bastante.